# How can i set the background color of the page uniform, even after scroll?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a page layout, which has the bootstrap `container`.
I am rendering pages using this layout.

In one page, my `div` is of just half the height of the screen. And there is another page that I am rendering, it is very big (I have to scroll down).

After setting the `background-color` of the `container`, on rendering the first page, only half the page's `background-color` is displayed, whereas for the second page, the `background-color` is uniform over the entire page.

**CSS**

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.mainlayout {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='container-fluid'>

    <div class='row'>
    Here i am rendering my data for each page. (Flask `jinja` templates)
    </div>

</div>
```

I am not sure how can I make the `background-color` uniform for each page, covering the complete screen.

Comment: please add your code with snippet

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
}

body{
  background:#ccc;
  color:#333;
}

.mainlayout {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class='container-fluid'>

    <div class='row'>
    Here i am rendering my data for each page. (Flask `jinja` templates)
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: why? explain how should looks